# Returning Count() from SOQL Query in a Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, salesforce, soql

I am trying to return the number of products of with the ProductName = EAP related to an Opportunity.  Here is my code:

```
function getProductTypes (oppId) { 

var result = sforce.connection.query("Select COUNT() From OpportunityLineItem where OpportunityId = '" + oppId + "' and PricebookEntry.Product2.Name IN ('EAP') "); 

return result; 

}
```

What I want to do is return the number of number of "EAP" products related to the opportunity so then in the below code block, I can determine another piece of code to run:

```
if(getProductTypes('{!Opportunity.Id}') >= 1){ 
//run this code!
}else{
//run this code instead!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of doubt - `alert()` or `console.log()` is your best friend ;) Closely followed by specification of the [QueryResult](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_query_queryresult.htm) object (it's in different document than the AJAX toolkit developer guide...)

This should work:

```
function getProductTypes (oppId) { 

    var result = sforce.connection.query(...);

    alert(result); // remove it once you're happy
    return result == null ? 0 : result.size;
}
```